# Sharepoint list column display either number or "N/A"

Tags: sharepoint

I'm making a list and in some columns, the majority of the entries will be a valid number between 3,000 - 18,000, and therefore I have make these columns as a number type column. However, there are entries that a number is not applicable and I need to show to users that for such particular entry, such column(s) will display "N/A" or "Excluded". But I'm not sure how to achieve this and at the moment I just leave those entry's columns blank, which may cause confusion to the users.

One of the stupid ways I can think of solving this, is to make 2 columns, one is named [amount (input)] another named [amount (display)] that the "input column" to be used for data entry and not showing in the "view" page, while the "display column" is a formula to show either the number entered in the "input column", or "N/A" if no number has been entered.

Is there a nicer way to make this happen instead of creating extra columns which make the list looks too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the single number column null-able and add some logic in your application to check first if the number is null.  If it is null, show 'N/A' or 'Excluded' in your view.

This way you wouldn't have to add an extra column to the database.

Comment: Hi @Rickest Rick, thanks for yours and can you show me how to do this in sharepoint (or if any tutorial site I can try to study it myself)? sorry that my knowledge on computer and sharepoint is very basic and don't know how to do it exactly,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: If you are writing the code for the Sharepoint app,  look at what was done here at the api call to re-assign nulls a new value.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33519307-0dc3-4b9d-829b-6766b77dfb68/change-nullable-value-in-list-using-sharepoint-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: If you are are just using the designer (not coding)... then start here.. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sharepoint/sharepoint_custom_list.htm

Comment: @AmuroChan did you find this answer useful to you?  Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: sorry that I still do not know how to do it, not sure if it is because of the sharepoint version (2010) I am using. Is it possible that if I input "0" into the column, it will show "Excluded", and if I input other number (say 18000) it will show "18,000" with the thousand separator?

Comment: Hi @AmuroChan Can you add your code to your question?  I'd like to see what you have so far.